# Can't install Apple app updates on a new Mac mini

Tags: mac-appstore

I just got a new Mac mini and I'm trying to update Apple apps as requested, e.g. Pages, Numbers etc. App store asks me to sign in to iCloud which is fine, then gives me 2 messages:

- Your request is temporarily unable to be processed.

followed swiftly by

- Could not assign applications to your account.

Any thoughts on how to resolve these issues?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try by signing out of and signing back in by going to Store → Sign Out in the Mac App Store Menu.

Comment: ^ that. Also try a reboot of your Mac & network, just in case... 'cheap & easy' first steps

Comment: Check your Payment method attached to the account.  Make sure there's no outstanding balance and/or that it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8644354)

> This message is basically directly related to the payment method that is linked to your Apple ID. This message will appear if you have an unpaid balance on your account or the payment method itself is invalid (for any reason).

To fix this you need to provide a payment method or chose “none”. If there is a payment due or if family sharing is enabled you won’t be able to choose “none”.

How to change your payment:

From [this Support article:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201266)

> Go to Settings > [your name] > iTunes 
>   & App Store.
>
> Tap your Apple ID, then tap View 
>   Apple ID. You might be asked to sign 
>   in.
>
> Tap Payment Information, then 
>   change or remove your information. 
>   To remove the payment method, 
>   select None. Get help if you don't see 
>   None or can't select it. Learn more 
>   about what payment methods 
>   are available in your country or region.
>
> Make sure that your name and billing address exactly match the information on file with your financial institution, then tap Done.

[If you can't choose None when you edit your Apple ID payment information](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203905) - Apple Support

Answer (score 0):

The Error message you got.

> Could not assign applications to your account.

Try following steps

1. Sign out then sign in again
2. Go to you Profile at https://appleid.apple.com/ and check your hardware been displayed correctly.
3. Restart you Mac.
4. Possibly.. This message will also appear if you have an unpaid balance on your account or the payment method itself is invalid (for any reason).

To stop these message, you will need to update your payment method. You can either provide a valid payment method or choose "none" to not associate any payment details with your Apple ID.